# How can I use Steps component?

Tags: vuejs3, primevue

I'm developing a system that uses Vue Prime framework, but I'm having some problems with the Steps component.

I've tried to run the example in their doc pages, but it isn't working, and I didn't understand at all how the component works

Thanks in advance for the help!

Here's the code example that i've used, I got it from here; https://primevue.org/steps/

This Error appears when I try to launch the code in my project, I've used the same code from the example of PrimeVue, and this happens.
[image]

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="card">
      <Steps
        :model="items"
        aria-label="Form Steps"
        :pt="{
          menuitem: ({ context }) => ({
            class: isActive(context.item) && 'p-highlight p-steps-current'
          })
        }"
      >
        <template #item="{ label, item, index, props }">
          <router-link
            v-if="item.route"
            v-slot="routerProps"
            :to="item.route"
            custom
          >
            <a
              :href="routerProps.href"
              v-bind="props.action"
              @click="$event => routerProps.navigate($event)"
              @keydown.enter="$event => routerProps.navigate($event)"
            >
              <span v-bind="props.step">{{ index + 1 }}</span>
              <span v-bind="props.label">{{ label }}</span>
            </a>
          </router-link>
        </template>
      </Steps>
    </div>
    <Toast />

    <router-view
      v-slot="{ Component }"
      :form-data="formObject"
      @prevPage="prevPage($event)"
      @nextPage="nextPage($event)"
      @complete="complete"
    >
      <keep-alive>
        <component :is="Component" />
      </keep-alive>
    </router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'
import { useToast } from 'primevue/usetoast'

const router = useRouter()
const toast = useToast()
const items = ref([
  {
    label: 'Personal',
    route: '/'
  },
  {
    label: 'Seat',
    route: '/seat'
  },
  {
    label: 'Payment',
    route: '/payment'
  },
  {
    label: 'Confirmation',
    route: '/confirmation'
  }
])
const formObject = ref({})

const nextPage = event => {
  for (let field in event.formData) {
    formObject.value[field] = event.formData[field]
  }

  router.push(items.value[event.pageIndex + 1].to)
}
const prevPage = event => {
  router.push(items.value[event.pageIndex - 1].to)
}
const complete = () => {
  toast.add({
    severity: 'success',
    summary: 'Order submitted',
    detail:
      'Dear, ' +
      formObject.value.firstname +
      ' ' +
      formObject.value.lastname +
      ' your order completed.'
  })
}

const isActive = item => {
  return item.route ? router.resolve(item.route).path === route.path : false
}
</script>
```

I've tried to change the code and search for answers of how that component works, but I didn't found anything at all

Comment: Steppers are a type of web component, [not unique to PrimeVue](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+a+stepper+component).  You'll need to provide more specific debugging information for your code.  "It doesn't work" could mean anything.  Is there an error? Since we can't run your code, please describe what the expected vs actual result of your code is.  Also, FYI all VuePrime code examples include links in the top-right to run the examples directly in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vkq6vh) or stackblitz

Comment: Sorry I'll try to be more precise then.

When I've tried using StackBlitz or Codesandbox to check that, I've found errors in the code too, and the code didn't run.

I'm gonna edit the post and show what appears in my code. 

Thx